# How can you write log files in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, logging, console, console-application

If I'm doing mass operations inside objective C, and a lot happens in the console... I cannot see it all happen in windows.

Instead of adding the argument `">>WriteLog.log"` what would the proper way to log the console inside of Objective C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed with James, NSLog is the first method I've ever used with Obj-C to log.

To expand on James' the NSLog requires a string object as it's first argument, with optional referenced variables as following arguments.

IE:

```
int someInteger = 5;
NSString *someString = @"STRING";
double someDouble = 2.34;

NSLog(@"This is an INT: %i, while this is a string: %@, while this is a double: %.2f",someInteger,someString,someDouble);

// Output: 2010-08-30 11:45:25.400 StackOverflow[380:a0f] This is an INT: 5, while this is a string: STRING, while this is a double: 2.34
```

To see where %@, %i, %.2f come from,  [study string format specifiers.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

Answer (score 9):

[`NSLog`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSLog) is the normal way to log to the console in Objective-C

You can use it like:

```
NSLog(@"My log string");
```

or

```
NSLog(@"%@", someStringObject);
```